# Checking if I am looking through a window using angles

Tags: mathematics, geometry, coordinates, lua, trigonometry

I am developing a mod for a game with a Lua api.

I am trying to detect if I am looking through from behind a window when I shoot an enemy. For context, when I shoot through this window I apply a special buff effect.

Characters lie on a map which is an xy coordinate system with 4 quadrants. 0, 0 lies at the center of the map.

I am doing a top-down view. I can get the xy position of my character, the xy position of the enemy character, and the 2 xy positions of the boundaries of the window.

I got the angle of the character relative to the angle of the window edges, and I got the angle of the character relative to the angle of the enemy.

here is an example:

```
player position -149.55355834961 -54.274295806885
target position -147.99998474121 -67.999992370605
left position -151.8394317627 -56.843517303467
right position -147.86442565918 -56.397045135498
angle target 96.457664489746
angle left 48.340045928955
angle right 128.51026916504
```

this is how I am calculating the angles (the game uses xz as the horizontal plane):

```
function getAngleBetween(object1, object2)
    -- y is height here
    local x1, y1, z1 = GetWorldPosition(object1)
    local x2, y2, z2 = GetWorldPosition(object2)
    local zDiff = z1 - z2
    local xDiff = x1 - x2
    local phi = math.atan2(zDiff, xDiff)
    if phi < 0 then
        phi = phi + (2 * math.pi)
    end
    local degrees = phi * (180/math.pi)
    return degrees
end
```

I used this code to check if the angle with the enemy was between the two sides of the window, but it gives inconsistent results. I think it has to do with how I am calculating the angles, and the coordinate system. For example, If I am facing north, it works. But if I am facing south, it doesn't.

```
    function isAngleBetweenDeg(leftAngle, rightAngle, checkAngle)
        
        leftAngle = math.mod(leftAngle,360)
        rightAngle =  math.mod(rightAngle,360)
        checkAngle =  math.mod(checkAngle,360)

        if leftAngle > rightAngle then
            return checkAngle >= leftAngle or checkAngle <= rightAngle
        end
        return checkAngle > leftAngle and checkAngle < rightAngle
    end
```

[image: diagram of cases]

How do I check if I am behind the window? as far as the game's API, you only need to know GetWorldPosition give me the coordinates.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that your window is an axis-aligned rectangle, and the player can see/shoot through it from all sides (even in through  one short side and out the opposite short side)? Or should the window be treated as a line segment, say, the line joining the bottom corners?

Comment: the window is not necessarily axis aligned (other than always standing vertically). it can have any orientation. It should be a line segment with the bottom corners. The player can walk anywhere around it.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't set this up with angles but rather with line segments. One line segment goes from your position to the enemy's position. The other line segment goes from the right to the left position of the window. If these two line segments cross each other, you see the enemy through the window.

Note that the two lines formed by the two players and the window will always intersect (unless they are parallel) so you can just compute the intersection point of the lines and then check whether the intersection is in-between the two players and in-between the sides of the window.